# Adding text after appendix item letter

Tags: formatting, appendices

I need to add a dash after appendix item's letter. It does need to appear on summary. I've tried to adding on the section title but the dash appear too far apart from the appendix letter. Below follows the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times New Roman with serif

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Dolor sit amet}
Have a look at \ref{app:foobar}

\begin{appendices}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\thesection\arabic{table}}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection\arabic{figure}}
  \section{-- Consectetur adipiscing elit} \label{app:foobar}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \caption{foo}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \textbf{ a } & \textbf{ b }\\
    1 & 3 \\
    2 & 4\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
  \section{Mauris euismod}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Shall this dash appear in any appendix section?

Comment: The easiest way would be `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}\ -- \ }` for most of appendix parts, but this would leave a trailing `--` in the cross-references, which is ugly and most certainly not wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

`\@seccntformat` is responsible for the typesetting of the section etc title numbers, it adds a `\quad` space after the number, as such `\section{-- foo}` places the dash too far to the right.

Redefinition of `\@seccntformat` with a wrapper macro `\mydash` replaces the `\quad` by `\csname the#1\endcsname\ \mydash\ }`, where `#1` is replaced by the relevant counter name, i.e. `section`, `subsection`, this means that all section levels will get this dash now.

The addition to the `ToC` either requires patching `\@sect` or using `tocloft` and writting the `dash` to the number box with `\cftsecaftersnumb`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times New Roman with serif
\newcommand{\mydash}{--}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Dolor sit amet}
Have a look at \ref{app:foobar}

\begin{appendices}
  \makeatletter
     % Changing the width of `Appendix A` in the ToC
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\protect\cftsecnumwidth}{10pt}}
   % Adding the `-` before the sectiont title in the ToC
   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsecaftersnumb}{\protect\mydash\ }}
  %\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsubsecaftersnumb}{\protect\mydash\ }} % If needed
  \renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname\ \mydash\ }
  \renewcommand\thetable{\thesection\arabic{table}}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection\arabic{figure}}
  \section{Consectetur adipiscing elit}  \label{app:foobar}
  \makeatother

    \begin{table}[h]
    \caption{foo}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \textbf{ a } & \textbf{ b }\\
    1 & 3 \\
    2 & 4\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
  \section{Mauris euismod}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but it must appear on summary or list of contents as well. Thank you Christian for the quick reply.

Comment: @RinaldiSegecin: See the update, please. Choose the spacings as you like, i.e. other than the `10pt` I have applied in there